# I want to clear the concept about object and instance using below condition

Tags: excel, vba

I have few questions in ref. of below two lines

```
Dim coll As Collection
Set coll = New Collection
```

1. which is the object in 2nd line `coll` or `collection`
2. What `New` & `Set` key word is doing in second line
3. What is instance

Answer (score 0):

(1) `coll` is object, more precisely: pointer/reference to some object in memory.

(2) `New` and `Set` are keywords reserved for object. `Set` is syntatically required when assigning *value* to an reference type variable (which point to an object in memory and the *value* is just reference to some address in memory).
`New` keyword is used to initialize object, i.e. allocate memory.

(3) Instance is an instance of a class. Class can have properties, methods, etc. But it's just a class, you cannot do much with it. To access properties or use methods, you have to instantiate that class, like you do with collection. When you have an instance of a class, you can use its methods, etc.